# How to retrieve more than 10,000 objects from Weaviate?

Tags: weaviate

I have Weaviate instance where I store 100k documents and I want to retrieve all of them from database in some way. Till now I was using REST GET /v1/objects (with modified python library), adding limit parameter, but that works only up to 10k.

I tried using offset to get over that limit, but as I found in the docs at https://weaviate.io/developers/weaviate/api/graphql/filters#performance-and-resource-considerations--limitations it doesn't help due to the offset-based implementation. It also states that I could change QUERY_MAXIMUM_RESULTS to a higher number that 10k, but it will hurt performance and I'm not sure how it will scale to really high numbers as it will fetch everything at once.

I want to be able to retrieve all documents from the database with arbitrarily high number of records, even 500k. I won't be doing this often, so it may work slower / in batch, but I want to have this option.

The only solution I came up with is to store all id's in different database and query Waeviate in multiple batches using filter with id and OR operator, but that seems too complicated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The correct way to do this is by using the Cursor API, which has been available since version 1.18.

- [Cursor API announcement](https://weaviate.io/blog/weaviate-1-18-release#cursor-api)
- [Video demonstrating the Cursor API](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NUlS-TNEH_0&t=179s)